# jquery ui dialog button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

With a jQuery UI dialog, I need to be able to set tooltips on buttons... I have the following code:

```
buttons: {
 'My Button' : function(e) {
    $(e.target).mouseover(function() {
       alert('test'); 
    });
 }
```

This allows me to do something on "mouseover" but only once the button has been clicked. What do I need to do in order to make this function before the button has been clicked?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're going to want to do is have a handler for the "open" event on the dialog. That handler will need to crawl up the DOM to the outer container `<div>` that the dialog code wraps your dialog content with.  From there, it needs to find the box where the buttons are, and then attach your handlers as appropriate.

I can't remember exactly what the class names are (use Firebug) but the dialog code uses pretty obvious class tags to mark what the different containers are. There's an outer container, and then after your content box there's a `<div>` for the buttons.  Again, bring up your dialog and use Firebug to see what the structure looks like.

You can set up an "open" handler in your initialization options.

Comment: $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:nth-child(1)').mouseover(function() {
 // do something
});

Comment: Yes that works, though if there are multiple dialogs on the page then you'd want to scope that by working up and then down from each particular dialog. Of course, if the same mouseover behavior is desired for all similar buttons on all dialogs, then that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

It may only fire events once it is clicked on because only that function is fired on click.

Just select that button the normal way (e.g. `$('#my-form button')`) and then do attach the `mouseover` event.

Comment: The problem is that the jQuery dialog code synthesizes the buttons on the fly.  They're not explicitly coded onto the page.

Comment: I'm sure they do appear as elements. Maybe not in the initial markup, but added via JavaScript. Just add the events once you know they've been included in the page.

Comment: Right, @alex, that's what I was getting at in my answer :-)